PIL image loading errors on Google Colab while not experiencing the same problem in my local environment
When Colab reaches the line train_MLP(MLP_net, train_loader, vali_loader, loss_fn, MLP_optimizer), there is no output for a long time (it should have outputted quickly theoretically because I set it to output every epoch, and it only takes 4 minutes to train 10 epochs on my GPU with worse performance than Colab's T4 GPU).
Colab's bottom status bar continuously shows train_MLP() > __next__() > _next_data() > fetch() > __getitems__() > <listcomp> > __getitem__() > open()
When I manually stop it after running for 5 minutes (or longer), I get the following output every time:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-350539942fd4> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Your graph
----> 2 train_MLP(MLP_net, train_loader, vali_loader, loss_fn, MLP_optimizer)
      3 # 4m/10 epoch on Radeon Pro 555X (Metal 3)
      4 torch.save(MLP_net.state_dict(), 'mlp_model.pth')

7 frames
<ipython-input-14-a164d6b9990f> in train_MLP(model, train_loader, val_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, num_epochs)
     13         correct = 0
     14         total = 0
---> 15         for images, labels in train_loader:
     16             images, labels = images.to(GPU_device), labels.to(GPU_device)
     17             optimizer.zero_grad() # Zero the parameter gradients to remove accumulated gradient from a previous iteration

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    629                 # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    630                 self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 631             data = self._next_data()
    632             self._num_yielded += 1
    633             if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    673     def _next_data(self):
    674         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 675         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    676         if self._pin_memory:
    677             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data, self._pin_memory_device)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     47         if self.auto_collation:
     48             if hasattr(self.dataset, "__getitems__") and self.dataset.__getitems__:
---> 49                 data = self.dataset.__getitems__(possibly_batched_index)
     50             else:
     51                 data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataset.py in __getitems__(self, indices)
    397             return self.dataset.__getitems__([self.indices[idx] for idx in indices])  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
    398         else:
--> 399             return [self.dataset[self.indices[idx]] for idx in indices]
    400 
    401     def __len__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataset.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    397             return self.dataset.__getitems__([self.indices[idx] for idx in indices])  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
    398         else:
--> 399             return [self.dataset[self.indices[idx]] for idx in indices]
    400 
    401     def __len__(self):

<ipython-input-8-27864cd2ba6e> in __getitem__(self, idx)
     26         img_path = self.image_paths[idx]
     27         label = self.labels[idx]
---> 28         image = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
     29 
     30         if self.transform:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode, formats)
   3284         exclusive_fp = True
   3285 
-> 3286     prefix = fp.read(16)
   3287 
   3288     preinit()

KeyboardInterrupt: 

At first, I came across this issue and modified my code by replacing ImageFolder with a custom Dataset class. However, the same problem persists (while it runs fine on my local machine).
Then, I attempted to re-upload the dataset to Google Drive, but the issue remained unresolved.
Finally, I updated the PIL package in Colab, but the problem still persists.
At this point, I can't think of any other solutions.

I can see that line 3286 in the Image.py module seems to attempt to read the first 16 bytes from a file object, possibly to identify the file's header information to determine its type and format. However, I have already re-uploaded my training images.
